# Antd calendar prevent selected when click inside date

Tags: reactjs, calendar, antd

In Ant Design Calendar component, I render button and when I clicked button also calendar `onSelect` function warking, but I have another logic when user click on calendar date,

so I want to make a distinction if user click whole date or button inside a date.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achive that, you need to stop propagation when clicked on the button.

```js
import { Calendar, Button } from "antd";

import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const clickOnDate = () => {
    alert("Clicked on date!");
  };

  const clickOnButton = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation(); // This does the trick!
    alert("Clicked on button!");
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Calendar</h1>

      <Calendar
        onSelect={clickOnDate}
        dateCellRender={() => (
          <span>
            <Button onClick={clickOnButton}>Click Me!</Button>
          </span>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/beautiful-ganguly-x33i8u?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark